# Extract element from nested list based on column name

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I trying to extract a single element from a nested numeric matrix based on the value of the column name in the list. Here's an example of the data. I'm thinking use a regex to match the column of the list of weights to a gather column of forecast for ets, arima and theta?

**CURRENT**

```
ets         arima        theta            list_of_weights
forecast.   forecast    forecast    (ets_weight:0.5, arima_weight:0.2,theta_weight:0.3)
forecast    forecast    forecast    (ets_weight:0.4, arima_weight:0.1,theta_weight:0.5)
```

**IDEAL**

```
model_type  model_fcst  weights
ets         forecast    0.5
ets         forecast    0.4
arima       forecast    0.2
arima       forecast    0.1
theta       forecast    0.3
theta       forecast    0.5
```

Comment: Do you have `list_of_weights` as a character column or `list` column? Can you provide data using `dput` ?

Answer (score 1):

We. can convert. to long format with `pivot_longer` after `unnest`ing the 'list_of_weights' and then get the weights from 'list_of_weights' column with `parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%        
    unnest(c(list_of_weights)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = ets:theta, names_to = 'model_type', 
                   values_to = 'model_fcst') %>%
    filter(str_detect(list_of_weights, model_type)) %>% 
    mutate(weights = readr::parse_number(list_of_weights)) %>% 
    select(-list_of_weights)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  model_type model_fcst weights
#  <chr>      <chr>        <dbl>
#1 ets        forecast       0.5
#2 arima      forecast       0.2
#3 theta      forecast       0.3
#4 ets        forecast       0.4
#5 arima      forecast       0.1
#6 theta      forecast       0.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ets = c("forecast", "forecast"), arima = c("forecast", 
"forecast"), theta = c("forecast", "forecast"), list_of_weights = list(
    c("ets_weight:0.5", "arima_weight:0.2", "theta_weight:0.3"
    ), c("ets_weight:0.4", "arima_weight:0.1", "theta_weight:0.5"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```